# Is the Minkowski sum of two Lebesgue measurable set measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $E,F \subseteq \mathbb R$ be Lebesgue measrable. Is the sum $E+F=\{x+y:x \in E,y \in F \}$ Lebesgue measurable as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Sierpiński showed the existence of measure zero sets $X$, $Y$ whose sum $X + Y$ is non-measurable. See [this paper](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~kcies/prepF/89A+A/89A+A.pdf) for a detailed discussion of this.

Comment: The link is broken, but via the wayback machine the paper seems to have been "Measure zero sets with non-measurable sum" by Krzysztof Ciesielski, H. Fejzic, and C. Freiling.