# Is $X+Y$ a Lebesgue measurable set of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given that $X,Y \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ are Lebesgue measurable, can we say that $X + Y = \{ x + y \mid x \in X, y \in Y \}$ is a Lebesgue measurable set?

Since $X$ is measurable, we know that for all $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, $m^*(E) = m^*(E \cap X) + m^*(E\setminus X)$. Similarly, since $Y$ is measurable, we know that for all $E' \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, $m^*(E') = m^*(E' \cap Y) + m^*(E' \setminus Y)$.

Not sure how to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342178/is-the-minkowski-sum-of-two-lebesgue-measurable-set-measurable).

Comment: Does this extend into $\mathbb{R}^2$ though?

Comment: Well actually yes we can define the cantor set on $I \times I$ to be in $\mathbb{R}^2$